# Cannot load "My Selling Tools" in a sandbox environment

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I've seen other postings where people can't load "My Selling Tools" and I happen to be in the same boat.

Support hasn't responded yet and I'm hoping to do a demo Monday of the Windows 8/Paypal API integration from http://paypal.github.io/Windows8SDK/  into WinRT apps - hence turning to may favorite net community, stack overflow :)

The link above gives a sandbox account to allow for third party access, so trying to add that account to allow the third party access but can't even bring up the selling tools to do so. I was able to bring up the selling tools from my main login, but not from within the sandbox login.

Once I login to the sandbox environment and try to access "My Selling Tools" it just hangs. The browser doesn't matter, same result across browsers. I get nothing returned but the wait image. Actually anything on the left hand side hangs not just the selling tools. I've tried more than ten times all throughout the day.

Of course, the hope here is that someone from the PayPal Technical team replies.

I can't wait another hour on hold, I just can't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll make sure this gets escalated. As a workaround, you can log in to your sandbox account and then paste this URL in your browser: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/customerprofileweb?cmd=_profile-api-access. Could you also reference this post in your ticket if you have not done so yet?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Where can I find options 2-4 from here - I dont see the same options available on that URI to set the third party permissions. I get three columns "Account Information" "Financial Information", and "Selling Preferences" . http://paypal.github.io/Windows8SDK/

Comment: Does this URL work for you https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_profile-api-list-auths?

Comment: how about this one https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_profile-api-add-authorization&grantapi=true

Comment: Dennis and I spoke, the resolution was to upgrade my sandbox account to a premier account and the above links then worked. It's my understanding a new api may be available shortly as well for Windows 8.

Comment: PS I still have to use the above links - I cannot click on the left hand nav to get it to load.

Answer (score 5):

I was having the same issues getting into any option on the left in Paypals seller tools, but I stumbled onto the solution.

The links on the left are incorrect. They all begin with "www.beta-sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/..."

The issue is that "beta-" in the URL is invalid.

Using Chrome:
1) Right-click on the option on the left you want to get into
2) Click "Copy Link Address" in the pop-up menu
3) Paste it into the address bar
4) Remove "beta-" from the URL (see the "Profile / My Selling Tools" URL example below)
That's it.

INVALID:
https://www.beta-sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_profile-display-handler&tab_id=SELLER_PREFERENCES

CORRECT:
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_profile-display-handler&tab_id=SELLER_PREFERENCES

Hope this helps.

Dave

Comment: My link shows as: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/customerprofile/summary.view?actionId=setSelectedTab&tab_id=SELLER_PREFERENCES&nav=0.5.10  which in turn causes this to load with the 'wait' image  https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/customerprofile/summary.view

Comment: While your in the "my profile" page view (where the wait image is just spinning), Hover over one of the 4 links on the left ("My business info", "My money", "My settings", "My selling tools") and check out the link info that displays at the bottom of the browser. The <a href used points to "www.beta-sandbox.paypal.com..." Copy and paste that URL into the address bar, then remove the "beta-" from the URL. I'm doing testing for a client right now and it works for all of my broken paypal links.It's kind of a pain to have to copy every link and edit it, but it works.

Comment: I wish it was that easy for me :)  None of mine point to beta, they are all www.sandbox...